# Random lottery system

Tags: excel-formula

i'm currently working on a lottery system at work. I have a list of names and number of tickets they want. If "name 1" has 5 tickets he will randomly get 5 numbers in the table. There are 200 possible tickets. And also i want empty fields if theres not 200 tickets (see image)

I was thinking of maby create a new list if possible? where i add new lines if "name 1" has 5 tickets like this:

[image: How to make list like this?]

and so on... Then adding RANDBETWEEN(1-200) after. and use a lookup to the main table?

Anyone have a idea or direction i can further study? thx!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest problem doing this with `RANDBETWEEN(1-200)` is going to be sampling without replacement. At least I'm assuming you do not want the possibility of duplicated numbers.

This is most likely going to require VBA where you can have explicit control over a looping process that draws numbers from a list randomly and **does not replace** the possible numbers once selected.

Comment: Ah, yes of course. Didn't even think about that. Going to see what i can do in vba. Thx for quick response :D